# How to calculate if a pair of coordinates is inside a polygon without using an external library?

Tags: coordinates, point-in-polygon

I have a latitude/longitude pair and I want to see if another latitude/longitude set comprising a polygon contains them. I once read (in this SE site if I'm not mistaken) that you usually need to take the projection with the right properties, use it to project the coordinates and work with projected points. In order to calculate the area for example, one can use an equal area projection.

My first thought was to do the same. Each side of the polygon is the "shortest distance" between two vertices. That is a "great circle" arc so I need one projection that shows great circle arcs as straight lines. Then I chose one arbitrary vertex as the tangent point, I project the polygon and the point and finally, I am calling a `contains(Point p)` on the projected polygon. While searching for the right projection to use, I found [this USGS publication](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/plate-1.pdf)<sup>(1)</sup> where it mentions for Lambert Conformal Conic that

> Great circle lines are *approximately* straight.

Emphasis mine. The only projections that seems to preserve great circle arcs is Gnomonic:

> It is **the only projection** in which any straight line is a great circle, and it is the only projection that shows the shortest distance between any two points as a straight line.

Again, emphasis mine. It seems that Gnomonic is the way to go *but* according to another publication `Map projections - A working manual` Gnomonic projection is only used in it's spherical form with no solution for the ellipsoid. (chapter 22 p.164)

So either with Lambert Conformal Conic or Gnomonic, a margin of error is introduced and the result is approximate and not exact. I followed the solution of using a gnomonic projection and as far as I could tell, it works fine for my needs. But as I am an amateur in GIS, I am interested in knowing what is the *right* way of making this computation.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> `THE PROPERTIES AND USES OF SELECTED MAP PROJECTIONS By Tau Rho Alpha and John P. Snyder 1982` in case this one goes to meet the long list of broken links.

Comment: You are using python?

Comment: @BERA No I am using C# but I deliberately omitted it as I would like to consider the question language agnostic. I actually tagged it C# and I regretted it at the last moment. :)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147881/51035 might have some pointers, cffk is the instance on this kind of stuff

Comment: @bugmenot123 Indeed that's what I needed. cffk uses Gnomonic and gives a good explanation on the accuracy. Thanks!